# How to center an image horizontally while pushing the bottom (unknown resolution) and keep centered if window is too narrow

Tags: html, image, css, background-position

Let's say I have an image of **unknown resolution**. I want to center it horizontally, **even if the window is narrower than the picture**, and push the bottom of the window to fit the height of this picture.

How can I achieve that with **css only**? (no javascript)

Obviously the picture will be in an < img > tag since this is the only way to push the bottom. Align it center is easy, the hard part is to keep it centered **just like a background-position:center top** because when simply centering this < img > tag it will hit the left border of the window instead of overflowing hidden and staying centered.

Thanks!

Comment: I am having a hard time understanding this question. You want an image that behaves like a background with it's position set to `center top`? What is it about `background-position:center top` that isn't how you want it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Voila:
https://jsfiddle.net/gwja6f6z/

HTML:

```
<div id=main>
    <div id=imgwrp>
        <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/94/Ingres%2C_Self-portrait.jpg" border=0>
    </div>
</div>

<p>
The picture stays center and does not hit the borders of the window when window is too narrow, and this text is pushed without knowning the height of the picture.
</p>
```

CSS:

```
html, body {
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  text-align:center;
  overflow-x:hidden;
}

#main {
  position:relative;
  left:50%; /* This div is just a 0px width line in middle of window  */
  width:0;
  overflow-x:visible;
  text-align:center;
}

#imgwrp {
  display:inline-block; /* Image container width is same as image itself */
  position:relative;
  margin:0 auto 0 auto;
}

#imgwrp img {
  display:block;
  position:relative;
  margin-left:-50%; /* The image is pushed left by 50% its container width */
}
```

Comment: I don't see how this is any different other than more divs/code than with the answers I provided you, especially the last one...

Here for example is the same result with the code block from my last example: https://jsfiddle.net/gwja6f6z/4/

Removing useless code/divs in the process.

Comment: That said, I'm glad you've found a way that works for you. I'm still clueless however to what you're seeing in terms of it being "stretched" but yea that's not the behavior I'm noticing in any of the examples.

Either way I hoped any of the examples I posted could provide you or anyone else with further help or so!

Comment: Then that's indeed a bug in the Linux build of Firefox in terms of display:flex. Nothing in my code actually makes such thing happen. But well I'm glad you did find a way to fix it for your use. In general the code should've been cross platform/browsers. So not really sure why it had such a different behavior for you. Might be useful to next time mention you're on a linux/build of browser and/or provide pictures to clarify what you're seeing. 

Either way, if any of the provided answers provided you with any insight, then I'm glad either way.

Comment: I can't really trouble shoot the problem as I'm not experiencing it, and do not use any Linux distros, so without any direct insight into the problem, I can't really report anything regarding it. Feel free to do so yourself though.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this with the img tag you can use the following two codes:

```
object-fit:cover;
object-position:50% 50%;
```

These are pretty much the same as background-size and background-position.

For example how this would be done in code:

```css
html,body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%
}
img {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  object-position: 50% 50%;
  float:left;
}
div {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #222;
  display:flex;
  color:#fff;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content:center;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://www.rafaeldejongh.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/GlitchSkull1.jpg" alt="Rafael De Jongh - Glitch Skull"/>
<div>  
  <p>Other Content</p>
</div>
```

You can view this as well on [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dewp6dcp/)

And in case you do want to have a full fluid background image that is set to 100% of the viewports width and height, you could also do this via the following code:

```css
html,body {
  width:100%;
  height:100%
}
#img {
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  max-width:100%;
  max-height:100%;
  background-image:url(https://www.rafaeldejongh.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/GlitchSkull1.jpg);
  background-size:cover;
  background-position:center center;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  float:left;
  display:inline-block;
}
#content {
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  background: #222;
  display:flex;
  color:#fff;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content:center;
}
```

```html
<div id="img"></div>
<div id="content"><p>Other Content</p></div>
```

[Also on JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dewp6dcp/1/)

Feel free to ask if you have any further questions!

Comment: until Edge gets around to implementing object-fit, you'll need this polyfill to make it work in latest Edge browser (and older IE obviously) https://github.com/bfred-it/object-fit-images/

Comment: @scottohara 

It's indeed a shame that Edge still hasn't supported this quite useful css trick, but thanks as well for sharing that library, quite useful indeed!

Comment: The image is keeping aspect ratio and is not being stretched as it uses the cover property. Or how exactly do you want it?

Comment: Oh alright, if I get you completely then it would be something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/dewp6dcp/3/ 

You can view the result in full via this link: https://jsfiddle.net/dewp6dcp/3/show/

Comment: If you do not have any reset/normilizer applied then it should not rescale, make sure your img tag is not set to max-width:100%. It also does not hit any border as it is centered in the middle of another container which has overflow:hidden.

Either I'm still misinterpreting your question, or something else is amiss. But currently the above jsfiddle has a full 100% width&height image that is centered in a flex div with overflow:hidden on it.

Comment: I'm just using Chrome with this latest JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/dewp6dcp/3/ || https://jsfiddle.net/dewp6dcp/3/show/ The main code is not updated yet. In general it should never lose aspect ratio as it uses the cover functionality, so it is covered over the whole container. So I'm not really sure why you keep referring to it being stretched/losing aspect ration. But let me know if the last link is what you're after or, if it's something completely different!